# Numeric style biblatex with citation [1] in mainmatter despite citations in frontmatter?

Tags: biblatex, front-matter

Using biblatex with a numeric style and a book class with frontmatter/mainmatter, would it be possible to have all citations in the frontmatter appear *last* in the list of references, as if the frontmatter (from biblatex's point of view) appeared *after* the mainmatter?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,style=nature]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{hydrogen,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}}
@misc{neodymium,
  author = {Luthor, Lex.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\frontmatter
\cite{neodymium}

\mainmatter
\cite{hydrogen}

\backmatter
\printbibliography[title={List of references}]

\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, references in the "List of references" are printed in the same order as they were given in the document, so `neodymium` would be listed before `hydrogen` in the "List of references".
This also means that the citation in the frontmatter would be labelled `[1]` in the text and the first citation in the mainmatter would be labelled `[2]`.
This is just as expected with the numeric style as often used in science and engineering theses.

I wonder if there is some way to make the first citation in the mainmatter be `[1]` (because it might be jarring for the reader to see the first citation in the first chapter be something like `[11]`, it may make them wonder what they missed), without having a separate `\printbibliography` for the frontmatter (nor using `refsection` or `refsegments`, because I don't think they will help in this case). Preferably any citations in the frontmatter would simply be appended to the end of "List of references", as if the frontmatter was processed *after* the frontmatter by `biblatex`.

I think this would be hard to achieve. But I'd like to hear if anyone knows better?
Would something like this be possible? Have I missed something obvious?

I have read the Sorting section in the biblatex manual, and read these related (but not-very-pertinent) questions on TeX.SE

- [Numbering issue in \printbiblography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540610/numbering-issue-in-printbiblography/540615)
- [BibLaTeX: have two separate bibliographies with consecutive numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306678/biblatex-have-two-separate-bibliographies-with-consecutive-numbering)
- [Citations out of order with appendix and split bibliographies in backmatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244150/citations-out-of-order-with-appendix-and-split-bibliographies-in-backmatter)